# Read json data with get method from from php api

Tags: php, rest, get

[image: advance rest client (get method)]

How to read the username and password from server end. If I use POST method instead of GET then I can easily read this by

```
$REQUEST = file_get_contents('php://input');
$REQUEST = json_decode($REQUEST, true);
echo json_encode($REQUEST);
```

this code. and I can get the response 
    {"username": "muradcse1", "password": "1122"}

but what is way to read data of json format if the method is get? I need this format for get method also.

please help.

Comment: json_decode() would allow you to render all json data into php arrays.

Comment: Thank you @Idealcastle what should I pass in json_decode() function?
Suppose
$REQUEST = file_get_contents('php://input');
$REQUEST = json_decode($REQUEST, true);
"file_get_contents('php://input')" is not working for get method but for the post.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking "How do I get variables from an incoming GET request to my server?", then you need to specifically set those GET variables. 
 Example:

```
<?php

$username = $_GET['username']; //GET the username
$password = $_GET['password']; //GET the password

//Assign to array print as JSON
$json = array(
  'username' => $username,
  'password' => $password
);
echo json_encode($json); //Print JSON
```

Data submitted to your server as a GET request is NOT submitted as JSON. Rather it is submitted as URL_Encoded.

Comment: Thank you,
So you are saying that it is not possible to send request like my attached image.
Either I have to use https://youtulee.com/api_tst.php?t=login&username=muradcse&password=****
or, if I want to use {"username": "muradcse1", "password": "1122"} format to pass username and password, then I have to use POST or something else but not GET. Isn't  it?

Comment: Exactly, the parameters for a GET request are sent in the URL.
`site.com/?username=john&password=doe`

Comment: Thank you so much @sudo soul